# R: Plotting abline onto scatter plot with dummy variable set as 1

Tags: r

I want to plot this line using the abline() function in R onto a 2D scatter plot:

[image]

I've tried this below, but it seems the third number, which I want to represent the dummy variable, doesn't work no matter what the value is.

```
abline(28.2879, 42.5551, 1)
```

Do I need to include the linear regression lm(...) in my abline function?

Comment: No, you don't need a regression result. I don't know what your scatter plot is of, but your plot has a single `x` (horizontal) axis and a single `y` (vertical) axis, and you're trying to specify 2 `x`s and a `y`. If you look at `?abline` you'll see the third argument (your attempt for `x2`) is actually a y-intercept if you want a horizontal line. My guess is by specifying `1` as the third argument you are successfully plotting a horizontal line with y-intercept `1`, which happens to be out of bounds of your plot. Try simplifying to `abline(28.2879, 42.5551)`.

Comment: Well - I'm half right. `abline` will actually plot multiple lines if you give it multiple specifications - so you are getting a horizontal line with y-intercept 1 as well as a line with intercept 28 and slope 42.6. If you have a certain value of `x2` in mind, just add it on to the intercept term.

Comment: I suspect you actually want a contour plot although you really should show us what sort of scatterplot you are actually contemplating. That function actually determines a plane in three dimensions, but the pseudo-3d displays are very difficult to read accurate values from.

Comment: No, I want a scatter plot. Gregor I don't have a specific value in mind for x2 -- I just want to be able to plot a line with abline where the dummy variable is 0, and another line where the dummy variable is 1

Comment: Are you opposed to 2 calls to `abline`?:  `abline(28.2879, 42.5551); abline((28.2879 + 1), 42.5551)` where you just add whatever you need to ass for the dummy variable?  In your example, you would add 1 to the intercept.

Comment: @jota Interesting, this seems to be what I was looking for. Why does adding the coefficient of x_2 to the intercept work?

Comment: That's the impact of a dummy variable.  It changes the intercept (moves the line up or down), not the slope.  Think about it: if the value is 0, you get the first line, and if the value is 1 you would just be adding a constant value (1 * the coefficient), thus it adds with the intercept.

Comment: And this is a contour plot, as 42 suggested you were looking for. Even though it has only 2 contour lines.